# how to add a button to gmail compose bar using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am new to chrome extension, I want to add a button to Gmail compose bar like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prospero-for-gmail/ldckbomjhgdfophpnobhhlijfgnleajh). I tried some of Gmail API to achieve but couldn't find my solution.
If anyone has the idea what will be the approach

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [gmail-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmail-js) npm package. It provides a lot of interface to communicate with the Gmail App for your chrome extension. I am currently working on a chrome extension myself that is supposed to work with the Gmail app, and it has made my life so much easier.

Look at the `gmail.tools.add_toolbar_button` function in the documentation for this particular case.

There are a few things that you need to be careful of though. For example, you can not use the apis this package provides in your content script, you'll have to inject it to the page DOM. The [brolierplate example](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail-chrome-extension-boilerplate) is very helpful to get you started.

Also, the communication between the injected file and `content_script` can not be done using `chrome.runtime` API, you will have to use `window.postMessage` API for that.

Good luck.